# Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component on set state

Tags: react-native, setstate

how we can use setState in componentDidMount() or how we can change state value?.
While using below code getting error

> Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    if(this.state.rmSec==0){
      this.setState({
        rmSec:59,
        rmMin:this.state.rmMin-this.state.minus,
      })
    }else{
      this.setState({
        rmSec:this.state.rmSec-this.state.minus
      })
    }

    if(this.state.rmMin==0){
      this.setState({
        rmSec:0,
        rmMin:0,
      })

    }


  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: with code above is nothing wrong, error come elsewhere. show please render function. good article about setState: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b

Comment: @dbvt10 setState inside componentDidMount will lead to memory leakage. so warning will show

Comment: intersting. any source? in official docs is nothing about this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: please share your component code in detail

Comment: @AravindS now you can see the code

Comment: @ShibinRajuMathew if you remove the setInterval, is the state getting updated?

Comment: @AravindS state is updating but always getting the warning

Comment: @ShibinRajuMathew Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by clearing interval on unmount

```
componentWillUnmount () {
    this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking `isMounted` before calling setState() does eliminate the warning, but it also defeats the purpose of the warning, since now you will never get the warning (even when you should!).The primary use case for `isMounted()` is to avoid calling setState() after a component has unmounted, because calling setState() after a component has unmounted will emit a warning. More here : https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html. So try like

```
 constructor(props) {
       this.state = {isMounted: false}
    }
 componentDidMount() {
       this.setState( { isMounted: true }, () => {

    });
}
componentWillUnmount() {
       this.setState( { isMounted: false } )
}
```

**Warning:** isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain Javascript Classes. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks.Looks like an RN issue and it will get fixed soon i guess

Comment: componentDidMount(){
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    if(this.state.rmSec==0){
      this.setState( { isMounted: true }, () => {
        rmSec:59;
        rmMin:this.state.rmMin-this.state.minus;
      });
    }else{
        this.setState( { isMounted: true }, () => {
        rmSec:this.state.rmSec-this.state.minus;
      });
    }

    if(this.state.rmMin==0){
      this.setState({
        rmSec:0,
        rmMin:0,
      })
      
    }


  }, 1000);
}

Comment: for the third setState, its missing. can you add the condition for that also and try once

Comment: Again Same issue...
`componentDidMount(){
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    if(this.state.rmSec==0){
      this.setState( { isMounted: true }, () => {
        this.setState({
          rmSec:59,
          rmMin:this.state.rmMin-this.state.minus,
        });
        })
    }else{
      this.setState( { isMounted: true }, () => {
        this.setState({
          rmSec:this.state.rmSec-this.state.minus,
        })})}
    if(this.state.rmMin==0){
      this.setState( { isMounted: true }, () => {
      this.setState({
        rmSec:0,
        rmMin:0,
  })} }}, 1000);}`

Comment: @ShibinRajuMathew That looks weird..can you stack trace which line is causing the error?